# How to send the data from server to client in node.js

Tags: jquery, node.js

In index.js,I'm able to get the data in the console.But I'm trying to display it in the browser.How to send data from index.js to html page?can anyone please help me out ...

My code in index.js:

```
 walk(dirctory, function(filePath, stat) {
       console.log(filePath); //able to get data 
      $("#table").val(filePath);
    });
```

My html:

```
<script src="javascripts/script.js"></script>
<script src="javascripts/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>

    <div id="box"> 
        <h2>DOWNLOAD</h2>
           <h> Download MLabs ".tgz" files for one month </h>
            <div id="text">
                    <form id="download" method="post" action="/download">
                    <center>
                        <span class ="mandatory" style="color:red">*</span>
                        <label>Year :  <select id ="year" name="year">
                        <option value="select year:" selected>Select year:</option>
                        <option value="2009">2009</option>
                        <option value="2010">2010</option>
                        <option value="2011">2011</option>
                        <option value="2012">2012</option>
                        <option value="2013">2013</option>
                        <option value="2014">2014</option>
                        <option value="2015">2015</option>      
                        </select>
                        </label></br></br>

                        <span class ="mandatory" style="color:red">*</span>
                        <label>Month :  <select id ="month" name="month">
                        <option value="select month:" selected>Select month:</option>
                        <option value="January">January</option>
                        <option value="February">February</option>
                        <option value="March">March</option>
                        <option value="April">April</option>
                        <option value="May">May</option>
                        <option value="June">June</option>
                        <option value="July">July</option>
                        <option value="August">August</option>
                        <option value="September">September</option>
                        <option value="October">October</option>
                        <option value="November">November</option>
                        <option value="December">December</option>
                        </select>
                        </label></br></br>

                        <span class ="mandatory" style="color:red">*</span>
                        <label>Number of files to download :  <select id ="files" name="files">
                        <option value="select value:" selected>Select value:</option>
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="100">100</option>
                        <option value="150">150</option>
                        <option value="200">200</option>
                        <option value="ALL">ALL</option>
                        </select>
                        </label></br></br>

                            <input type="submit" name="submit" onclick="createFormElement()" value="Download" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="reset" value="Reset" />
                    </center>
                </form>
              </div>
    </div>

<div id="fileDiv"></div>
</script>
```

My index.js :

```
router.post('/download', function(req, res, next) {

    var year = req.body.year;
    var month = req.body.month;
    var limit = req.body.files;

function walk(currentDirPath, callback) {
    var fs = require('fs'), path = require('path');
    fs.readdirSync(currentDirPath).forEach(function(name) {
        var filePath = path.join(currentDirPath, name);
        var stat = fs.statSync(filePath);
        if (stat.isFile()) {
            callback(filePath, stat);
        } else if (stat.isDirectory()) {
            walk(filePath, callback);
        }
    });
}


var dirctory ="/usr/local/ndt-files"+"/"+year+"/"+month;
walk(dirctory, function(filePath, stat) {
   console.log(filePath);
  $("#table").val(filePath);
});


    var stream = fs.createWriteStream('views/downloadInput.txt');
    stream.once('open', function(fd) {
    stream.write(year);
    stream.write('/');
    stream.write(month);
    //stream.write('/');
    //stream.write(limit);
    stream.end();
    }); 

    child = exec("/usr/local/src/node-v0.10.35/nodeprograms/views/scriptformonth.sh",   
    function (error, stdout, stderr) {

        if (!error) {

            console.log(stdout);

        } else {

            res.send(error);

        }
        });
});
```

Comment: can anyone please help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think of web servers as black boxes that receive requests as inputs and output a response. When you use a web browser to send an HTTP request to a web server, the web browser will receive the response.

So to answer your question, on the server side, there's nothing you have to do to send the response to a particular client. Just use `res.send('whatever')`, and whatever client made the request will get that response.

Comment: Here,in the callback function,Idon't have request and response .Then how can I send it .walk(dirctory, function(filePath, stat) {
   console.log(filePath);
  $("#table").val(filePath);
});

Comment: You have access to `res` inside of the `router.post` callback. This is why it's important to properly indent and format your code :)

Answer (score 0):

You are only sending the response back to the client when there is an error using `res.send(error)` and completely ignoring the other scenario. You will need to send the output as well using `res.send(..)`.

Make the following change in your code -

```
function (error, stdout, stderr) {

    if (!error) {

        console.log(stdout);
        // send the output here - 
        res.send(stdout);

    } else {

        res.send(error);
      }
    });
```